# Excluding certain area around feature using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, proximity

I have a problem for class where I only need features for a map that are at least 200m away from roads. I have been using the Clip and Near tools to this point, but I'm having trouble finding an "exclude" tool or something like it.

Comment: There's a couple of ways to get there, including Erase and Intersect with Delete or FeatureClassToFeatureClass (copying the non-deleted features).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the features intact, e.g. not erase away parts of features:

1. [Select By Location](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) and select features that are within a distance of 200 m of roads
2. [Switch selection](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/switching-the-selected-set-in-a-table.htm) to select the features that are not within 200 m.
3. [Copy Features](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm) to copy the selected features